# Restrict user to input text in skype bot and force to select from card options

Tags: bots, skype, dialogflow-es

I have a created a simple Skype Chatbot. Which at one point asks user if they want to continue with an option [Yes] [No]. I want to force user to click on either of these button. Because if they enter a text manually like, yes, no, Y, y, No etc... bot gets mad and looses it's context. Behind the scene I am using Dialogflow.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to restrict input in that way, but your Dialogflow agent should easily be able to handle natural language input. You should ensure your intents have a sufficient number of [training phrases](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents#training-phrases) (around 10 minimum) that cover a range of possible inputs.